# ImageMagick installation in Docker Alpine

Tags: docker, imagemagick, alpine-linux

So I have this Dockerfile that attempts to install ImageMagick the following way:

```
FROM ruby:2.4-alpine

...

RUN apk --update add imagemagick

...
```

The point is that the container doesn't recognizes the `file` utility (for content-type detection).

Local environment (Mac OSX, installed imagemagick with brew):

```
> file --version
file-5.25
magic file from /usr/share/file/magic

> convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.9-5 Q16 x86_64 2017-08-03 
http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype jng jpeg ltdl lzma png tiff xml zlib
```

Docker Alpine container (accessed to the shell using `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID`):

```
> file --version
sh: file: not found

> convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.5-9 Q16 x86_64 2016-10-21         
http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2016 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher Modules
Delegates (built-in): fontconfig freetype gslib jng jpeg lcms ltdl png ps tiff webp zlib
```

Also tried installing `imagemagick-dev` by itself, and both of them combined without any luck (shouldn't make a difference since the first one is a dependency of the latter, I guess).

The question is, **how can I install this in the Alpine container?** I think I'm missing something but can't figure it out.

By the way, I can't rely on another function other than `file` for content-type detection since I'm using a framework that explicitly uses this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar Q/A that helped me on stackoverflow:
[imagemagick installation in docker alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415869/imagemagick-installation-in-docker-alpine)

The file utility is not part of ImageMagick, it is a standard utility. You can read more about it on wikipedia:
[File (command)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)).

On Alpine Linux, you can install it with `apk add --no-cache file`. As shown in the following terminal session:

```bash
/ # file /etc/group
/bin/sh: file: not found
/ # apk add --no-cache file
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community/x86_64
/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/2) Installing libmagic (5.32-r0)
(2/2) Installing file (5.32-r0)
Executing busybox-1.26.2-r5.trigger
OK: 9 MiB in 13 packages
/ # file /etc/group
/etc/group: ASCII text
/ #
```

Comment: @mic84 Thanks for the point, it's really helpful to include the essential parts.